# How to fill a section within c++ string?

Tags: c++, c, string

Having a string of whitespaces:

```
string *str = new string();
str->resize(width,' ');
```

I'd  like to
fill length chars at a position.

In C it would look like

```
memset(&str[pos],'#', length );
```

How can i achieve this with c++ string, I tried

```
 string& assign( const string& str, size_type index, size_type len );
```

but this seems to truncat the original string.
Is there an easy C++ way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason to dynamically allocate the string in your example?

Comment: @GMan - I don't want them as auto variable rather on heap in evil strdup() way

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In addition to `string::replace()` you can use `std::fill`:

```
std::fill(str->begin()+pos, str->begin()+pos+length, '#');
//or:
std::fill_n(str->begin()+pos, length, '#');
```

If you try to fill past the end of the string though, it will be ignored.

Answer (score 13):

First, to declare a simple string you don't need pointers:

```
std::string str;
```

To fill in a string with content of a given size, you can use the corresonding constructor:

```
std::string str( width, ' ' );
```

To fill in strings you can use the replace method:

```
 str.replace( pos, length, length , '#' );
```

You must do convenient checks. You can also directly use iterators.

More generally for containers (string is a container of chars), you can also use the std::fill algorithm

```
std::fill( str.begin()+pos, str.begin()+pos+length, '#' );
```

Comment: compiler still complains - any suggestions?

error: invalid conversion from `char' to `const char*'

error:   initializing argument 3 of `std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::replace(typename _Alloc::size_type, typename _Alloc::size_type, const _CharT*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]'

Answer (score 1):

with one of *replace(...)* methods ([documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html)) you can do everything you need