# Clarification needed in c++ erase function

Tags: c++, string, stl

So there was this question in recent [programming contest](https://codeforces.com/contest/1369/problem/B).
we have a test case in that question

```
8
11001101
```

Now the output I want is 1 but this line

```
cout << s.erase(0,6) << "\n"
```

gives 01 even though i want to remove elements from 0 to 6th index position.
How should i remove elements from 0 to 6 (including 6)

Here is the code for reference

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int t;  cin >> t;
    while(t--){
        long n; cin >> n;
        string s;   cin >> s;
        int index_l=0;
        int index_r=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(s[i]=='1'){
                index_l = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        for(int i=s.length(); i > index_l;i--){
            if(s[i] == '0'){
                index_r = i;
                break;
            }
        }/*
        cout << s.length() << "\n";
        cout << index_l << " " << index_r << "\n";
        */
       if(index_r == 0) cout << s << "\n";
        else cout << s.replace(index_l,index_r,"0");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How many elements do you think are in "0 to 6 (including 6)"? Did you try playing with the code at all, such as passing different arguments to see what happens? Also, I don't see any call to `erase` in the code.

Comment: 7 elements and i want to erase all 7 but the function only erases 6 :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at some documentation for [`std::string::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase). There's an overload that takes a starting **index** and a **count** of characters to remove. If you want to erase the first 7 characters then you should do:

```
s.erase(0, 7)
```

Just to be clear, the second parameter isn't a position. It's the number of characters to remove.

Comment: but then other test case fails :/

Comment: I just removed my ans, I got that to the range version. Sequence version is what he is using.

Comment: @AbhijeetSrivastava you need to figure it out youself why other test cases are failing! :) He just answered your question regarding `erase`.

Comment: @AbhijeetSrivastava Sorry, I don't know if the rest of your code is correct. I'm just answering your question about how `erase` works.

Comment: Ok,Using the above test case can you tell me what will be the output of s.erase(index_l , index_r) ?

Comment: @AbhijeetSrivastava The second parameter isn't a position, it's a **count**.  It will erase a total of `index_r` characters starting from index `index_l `.

Comment: Woah thanks that's where the problem began , i am so dumb :/

Comment: @AbhijeetSrivastava after going through the question, I believe that you only need to find the leading zeros and trailing ones in `s`. The answer is simply the 0's + 0 + 1's if the string is not already clear.

Comment: @brc-dd I think the logic is finding the leftmost 1 and rightmost 0 replacing everything in between with 0 and then printing the required string taking care of the fact that index of leftmost 1 should be lesser than rightmost 0 .

Comment: @AbhijeetSrivastava Just do some rough work exploring cases, you will see what I am saying. It's quite easy to get the logic. Try giving it a hit. [This solution](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VbGmsEWY6Jmw9lFo) will work like a charm! Enjoy practicing!

Comment: while we are at it can anyone tell me how to replace like this s.?(index1, index n , with some value)

Comment: @AbhijeetSrivastava what exactly do you expect from `index1 - indexn`? Filling every value from `index1` to `index n` with  some value??

Comment: Check out this thread: [How to fill a section within c++ string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891275/how-to-fill-a-section-within-c-string)

Comment: no no replacing everything from index 1 to index n(incl n) with single custom value

Comment: @brc-dd thanks for the solution , i wasted over an hour on this :)

Comment: @AbhijeetSrivastava Use something like: `std::fill_n(s.begin() + index_1, index_n - index_1 + 1, '1');`

Comment: @AbhijeetSrivastava If you want to use [`std::string::replace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) be aware there's a LOT of overloads. What you want is in there but it's not always obvious which one to use.

Comment: @brc-dd No way :/ (i asked about work experience but i thought its too much of talking so deleted it )

Comment: @AbhijeetSrivastava well that's the truth! :D (and seeing your comment deleted, I deleted my response too! || I am fresher at IIIT Kota with only an experience of about 3 yrs.)